# Does changing a file as a script is running affect the script?

Tags: bash

I have a script that is setup like such:

```bsh
cat file | while read line; do 
    
    # some stuff
    
done
```

If I change `file` as the script is running, does that affect the execution of the script? In addition, would the same be true if I rewrote the script as:

```bsh
while read line; do
    
    # some stuff
    
done < file
```

If it matters, changing the file might be anything from appending a line or two to wiping the file entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in both cases, the file *name* is only resolved once, but the file *contents* are read incrementally (streamed) throughout the script's runtime. The OS does not automatically provide any sort of isolation or versioning. If you change or append data within the same file (retaining its inode number and everything), the program will start seeing the new data through the same file handle as soon as the read pointer gets to that location.

But depending on how the script is written, **some amount** of data can be buffered before the script gets to processing it. In your 1st script, the pipe between 'cat' and 'while' can hold a large chunk of data (64 kB, afaik) and this means that 'cat' will have already read much further than the 'while' loop is processing currently.

For example, if the loop is currently processing the 3rd line, then 'cat's read pointer might already be at the 100th line, having already read and buffered all data up to this point. And if the script is currently processing the last few lines, then 'cat' will have already read all the way to end-of-file and stopped – so appending more data will *not* be noticed anymore.

In the 2nd example, there is no pipe and such large amount of buffering will not occur. However, the 'read' command still buffers data in small amounts – instead of reading byte-by-byte until the newline, it just reads a whole 4 kB of data at once. So when the loop is at the 3rd line, it may have also read the beginning of 4th or even 5th line.

Finally note that changing the file through a text editor might not always preserve the same file object – some text editors rename/delete the original and create a completely new file in that place. If this happens, it will *not* be noticed by your script as it ('cat' in the 1st example, 'bash' itself in the 2nd) will already have an open file handle and will continue reading from the same old file object.